# Bijections between $(0,1)^{r}$ and $ℂ^{r}$

Tags: real-analysis

Bijections between $(0,1)^{r}$ and $ℝ^{r}$ are known.

My **question** is about the existence of bijections between $(0,1)^{r}$ and $ℂ^{r}$ for $r∈ℕ$.

Comment: Do you know that there exists a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Think about space filling curves.

Comment: @ Git Gud: Yes, I know that there exists a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $ℝ²$.

Comment: @Chaos Then a bijection between $(0,1)^r$ and $\Bbb R^{2r}$ should be easy to find.

Comment: @Chaos Can you use the [Cantor-Schröder-Bersntein Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) (which, by the way, was first proved by Dedekind as you can see by the theorem's name)? If you can, just look at Dominic's answer and our comments.

Comment: @Git Gud : Thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah they are known, because there is an bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, look up for [space filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) which gives the main idea and as $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ that works too.

So at first you find the bijection between $(0,1)^r$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2r}$, and then you use the known bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, which gives you a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^{2r}$ to $\mathbb{C}^r$.

Comment: But I am looking for all cases of natural $r$, not only $r=2$.

Comment: @Chaos yeah I know my answer works for every natural number. What you exactly don't unterstand in the answer?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your nice answer.

Comment: @Chaos glad i could help

Comment: @BabakS. thanks :)